# Group by time intervals and additional attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have this data:

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'timestamp': ['2022-11-03 00:00:06', '2022-11-03 00:00:33', '2022-11-03 00:00:35', '2022-11-03 00:00:46', '2022-11-03 00:01:21', '2022-11-03 00:01:30'],
    'from': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'to': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B'],
    'type': ['Car', 'Car', 'Van', 'Car', 'HGV', 'Van']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create two sets of CSVs:

1. One CSV for each Type of vehicles (8 in total) where the rows will by grouped by / aggregated by time-stamp (for 15 minute intervals throughout the day) and by "FROM" column - there will be no "TO" column here.
2. One CSV for each Type of vehicles (8 in total) where the rows will by grouped by / aggregated by time-stamp (for 15 minute intervals throughout the day), by "FROM" column and by "TO" column.

The difference between the two sets is that one will count all FROM items and the other will group them and count them by pairs of FROM and TO.

The output will be an aggregated sum of vehicles of a given type for 15 minute intervals summed up by FROM column and also a combination of FROM and TO column.

1st output can look like this for each vehicle type:

[image]

2nd output:

[image]

I tried using Pandas `groupby()` and `resample()` but due to my limited knowledge to no success. I can do this in Excel but very inefficiently. I want to learn Python more and be more efficient, therefore I would like to code it in Pandas.

I tried `df.groupby(['FROM', 'TO']).count()` but I lack the knowledge to usit for what I need. I keep either getting error when I do something I should not or the output is not what I need.

I tried `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min', )).count()` but it seems I perhaps have incorrect data type.

And I don't know if this is applicable.

Comment: Can you please add an example of the code you have tried to solve this?

Comment: I was looking through dozens of topics and forums and could not find a way to apply this to my problem. I have tried multiple codes like `df.groupby(['FROM', 'TO']).count()` (which does not aggregate to time intervals) and `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min', )).count()` but I am getting an error Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex' and I dont know how to combine those.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have put some code examples in the edit including the resulting errors. I have also included a visualisation of expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, one approach could be as follows:

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd

# IIUC, you want e.g. '2022-11-03 00:00:06' to be in the `00:15` bucket, we need `to_offset`
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

# adjusting last 2 timestamps to get a diff interval group
data = {'timestamp': ['2022-11-03 00:00:06', '2022-11-03 00:00:33', 
                      '2022-11-03 00:00:35', '2022-11-03 00:00:46', 
                      '2022-11-03 00:20:21', '2022-11-03 00:21:30'], 
        'from': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
        'to': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B'],
        'type': ['Car', 'Car', 'Van', 'Car', 'HGV', 'Van']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

             timestamp from to type
0  2022-11-03 00:00:06    A  B  Car
1  2022-11-03 00:00:33    A  B  Car
2  2022-11-03 00:00:35    A  B  Van
3  2022-11-03 00:00:46    A  C  Car
4  2022-11-03 00:20:21    B  C  HGV
5  2022-11-03 00:21:30    C  B  Van

# e.g. for FROM we want:        `A`, `4` (COUNT), `00:15` (TIME-END)
# e.g. for FROM-TO we want:     `A-B`, 3 (COUNT), `00:15` (TIME-END)
#                               `A-C`, 1 (COUNT), `00:15` (TIME-END)
```

**Code**

```
# convert time strings to datetime and set column as index
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

# add `15T (== mins) offset to datetime vals
df.index = df.index + to_offset('15T')

# create `dict` for conversion of `col names`
cols = {'timestamp': 'TIME-END', 'from': 'FROM', 'to': 'TO'}

# we're doing basically the same for both outputs, so let's use a for loop on a nested list
nested_list = [['from'],['from','to']]

for item in nested_list:
    # groupby `item` (i.e. `['from']` and `['from','to']`)
    # use `.agg` to create named output (`COUNT`), applied to `item[0]`, so 2x  on: `from`
    # and get the `count`. Finally, reset the index
    out = df.groupby(item).resample('15T').agg(COUNT=(item[0],'count')).reset_index()
    
    # rename the columns using our `cols` dict
    out = out.rename(columns=cols)
    
    # convert timestamps like `'2022-11-03 00:15:00' to `00:15`
    out['TIME-END'] = out['TIME-END'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    
    # rearrange order of columns; for second `item` we need to include `to` (now: `TO`)
    if 'TO' in out.columns:
        out = out.loc[:, ['FROM', 'TO', 'COUNT', 'TIME-END']]
    else:
        out = out.loc[:, ['FROM', 'COUNT', 'TIME-END']]
        
    # write output to `csv file`; e.g. use an `f-string` to customize file name
    out.to_csv(f'output_{"_".join(item)}.csv') # i.e. 'output_from', 'output_from_to'
    # `index=False` avoids writing away the index
```

**Output (loaded in excel)**

[image: result loaded in excel]

**Relevant documentation**:

- [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`.to_offset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.frequencies.to_offset.html)
- [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html)
- [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)
- [`.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)
- [`df.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you very much. I will try to apply this as soon as I get to my PC. But from what I see, this seems to be exactly what I had in mind. I will revert if there is some error.

Comment: I have tried it, thank you for the comments inside the code. It works but is not fully what I need. For each output: "from" and "from-to", I need 8 separate CSVs (16 in total). I need to be able to distinguish the types of vehicles. Therefore individual CSVs could be named as follows: "output_from_car", "output_from_van" etc. and "output_from_to_car", "output_from_to_van" etc. Also, I would like to remove the indexing in the outputs. You have provided a comment about it, but I am not sure where to include this part of code. Thank you.

Comment: Actually scratch the last part. The index was actally very simple, I just made an error. Thanks.